# Use inner join to get data from 5 different tables

Tags: mysql, sql

I'm using plain MySQL and I have the following problem:

- Table A contains "seminars" (as ID) and "target_groups" (as ID)
- Table B contains "seminars" (as ID) and "topics" (as ID)
- Table C contains "ID" (which are seminars) and "title" (of seminars)
- Table D contains "ID" (which are target groups) and "title" (of
  target groups)
- Table E contains "ID" (which are topics) and "title" (of topics)

I need to capture all of them in one query. What I have so far:

```
select table_c.title as 'Seminars Title',
table_d.title as 'Target Groups Title'
from table_a 
inner join table_c on table_a.seminars=table_c.id 
inner join table_d on table_a.target_groups=table_d.id
```

so far this works fine.

But now I need to add Table B and Table E, too.As I cant get Table E through inner join with Table A, I need to use Table B. But I'm not sure how to do that?

Comment: @ErgestBasha thx, I'll have a look at them and make sure to create a better post next time!